# Use PowerShell to check connection between 2 remote servers over specific port

Tags: powershell, connection, port, remote-server

I'm trying to create a script that my customers can use to run a quick health check on an application of ours.  My goal is for them to be able to run the script directly on their workstation and get the results back.  The program is required to communicate to remote devices over specific ports, and I'd like the script to check those connections and display if they're working properly or not.

I found this script in a post a few years back that seems to work beautifully, but I can only seem to get it to check the connection between the workstation and the final device, not between our server and the final device:

```
$hostname = 'HOSTNAME'
$port = '104'

function Test-Port($hostname, $port) {
    # This works no matter in which form we get $host - hostname or ip address
    try {
        $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($hostname) |
              Select-Object IPAddressToString -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
        if ($ip.GetType().Name -eq "Object[]") {
            #If we have several ip's for that address, let's take first one
            $ip = $ip[0]
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Possibly $hostname is wrong hostname or IP"
        return
    }
    $t = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    # We use Try\Catch to remove exception info from console if we can't connect
    try {
        $t.Connect($ip, $port)
    } catch {}

    if ($t.Connected) {
        $t.Close()
        $msg = "Port $port is operational"
    } else {
        $msg = "Port $port on $ip is closed, "
        $msg += "You may need to contact your IT team to open it. "
    }
    Write-Host $msg
}

Test-Port $hostname $port
```

I have attempted running the last line as:

```
Test-Port -ComputerName 'SERVERSHOSTNAME' $hostname $port
```

But that throws:

```
Test-Connection : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts 
argument '153'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-Connection -ComputerName 'SERVERSHOSTNAME' $hostname $port
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```

I've also tried adding a

```
foreach ($server in $servers)
```

But it still seems to be checking the connection from the workstation (I checked this by putting in an IP on the server list that doesn't exist).  Anybody have any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: The code needs to be running from the machine that you want to check connectivity from. Look at running it in a PSSession on the machine that you want to test connectivity from.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do...  If they're on that machine, there's already a simple way to check it.  I'm trying to avoid them needing access to the machine.

Comment: They don't have to be on the machine. You just need the code to run in a session from the machine. Depending on the environment you can easily create a remote session. Of course then you have to worry about double hop problems...